# Edit WooCommerce product content based on category

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, actions

We are using Google Translate to automatically translate our website but we want to exclude products in a certain category. We already accomplished that for some products by placing the `<span class="notranslate">Span</span>` tag manually in the product descriptions and in the respective template files but now we want to do that for a larger quantity of products so we think using a hook would be a better way.

I want to achieve something like follows but I don't know how to correctly insert the NoTranslate span only for the product description:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'disable_translation' );
function disable_translation() {
    // If a product in the 'Cookware' category is being viewed...
    if ( is_product() && has_term( 'Cookware', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        //... Wrap the product description into notranslate span to disable the translation
        <span class="notranslate">???????????????????</span>
    }
}
```

Another way to do this probably is by editing the description.php in wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs as follows:

```
<?php if ( has_term( 'Cookware', 'product_cat' ) )  {
    echo "<span class='notranslate'>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<span>";
    } ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    echo "</span>";
<?php endif; ?>
```

But unfortunately this resulted in the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ‘endif’ (T_ENDIF), expecting end of file in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs/description.php on line 41

Have I misspelled something?

Could anybody kindly tell me how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways to do it, you can edit the template file `\woocommerce\templates\single-product\title.php` directly and change your title format there.  Otherwise, you can remove the WordPress hook in your `functions.php` file and add your own to override it which I borrowed from this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87857/add-a-span-around-a-product-title-in-woocommerce)

```
<?php
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'modify_woocommerce_template_single_title',5 );

    function modify_woocommerce_template_single_title() {
        if ( has_term( 'Cookware', 'product_cat' ) ) {
    ?>
    <h1 class="product_title entry-title"><span class="notranslate"><?php the_title(); ?></span></h1>
    <?php
        }
        else {
            ?><h1 class="product_title entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1><?php
        }
    }
    ?>
```

This will only change the single product page titles.  The shop page will keep the normal product titles as it uses a different hook but you can apply the same principles are remove the hook `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title` and override the function `woocommerce_template_loop_product_title`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! Much appreciated. We are looking to edit the product description though, is there also a similar way to do this for the description?

Comment: It depends what description you want to change, there's a filter you can hook into to modify the short description called 'woocommerce_short_description'